# Gin Sessions Stores the status and the code in the URL , I want to change that to make my URL cleaner

Tags: go, authentication, session, oauth-2.0, go-gin

I am making a backend using go,
the backend should get the google calendar of the user who login in the site using google account.
I am using gin to do the routing and sessions from this package github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions

this is my main method

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))
    router.Use(sessions.Sessions("goquestsession", store))

    router.GET("/", indexHandler)
    router.GET("/login", loginHandler)
    router.GET("/auth", authHandler)

    router.Run("127.0.0.1:9090")
}
```

login handler makes a new session for the user with random ID and send it to the user

```
func loginHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    state = randToken()
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    session.Set("state", state)
    session.Save()

    c.Writer.Write([]byte("<html><title>Golang Google</title> <body> <a href='" + getLoginURL(state) + "'><button>Login with Google!</button> </a> </body></html>"))
}
```

then I am using the auth handler to test the code and the state and get the calendar

```
func authHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    // Handle the exchange code to initiate a transport.
    session := sessions.Default(c)

    retrievedState := session.Get("state")
    queryState := c.Request.URL.Query().Get("state")
    if retrievedState != queryState {
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusUnauthorized, fmt.Errorf("Invalid session state: %s", retrievedState))
        return
    }
    code := c.Request.URL.Query().Get("code")
    tok, err := conf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext, tok)
    calendarService, _ := calendar.New(client)
    list, err := calendarService.CalendarList.List().Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }
    log.Println(list.Items[0].Summary)
    c.Status(http.StatusOK)
}
```

after writing the code I find out that the link of is like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090/auth?state=BuQ8DyhTEgivb6CatcTzJg8sk2Nb6EUStRkdgGVvDRE%3D&code=4/Qit73p0btO0RRM93_YmjlP0Ex2dqDLsP3JVdrnhNE7Y#
```

now after looking in the package github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions I didn't find a way to just be like this http://127.0.0.1:9090/auth and save the rest of the link somewhere else 
do I have to keep using URL like this if I am using Gin or there is some other way to make my link look cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I would personally add a route for the calendar, and then save the code to the session and redirect, so the auth handler url is never really visible, it just sends back a redirect to a clean url:

```
router.GET("/calendar", calendarHandler)
```

And then do:

```
func authHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    // Handle the exchange code to initiate a transport.
    session := sessions.Default(c)

    retrievedState := session.Get("state")
    queryState := c.Request.URL.Query().Get("state")
    if retrievedState != queryState {
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusUnauthorized, fmt.Errorf("Invalid session state: %s", retrievedState))
        return
    }
    code := c.Request.URL.Query().Get("code")
    session.Set("code", code)
    session.Save()
    c.Redirect(http.StatusFound, "/calendar")
}

func calendarHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    code := session.Get("code")
    tok, err := conf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext, tok)
    calendarService, _ := calendar.New(client)
    list, err := calendarService.CalendarList.List().Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }
    log.Println(list.Items[0].Summary)
    c.Status(http.StatusOK)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but that isn't the session library causing this. OAuth2, or at least the Google implementation, is the cause. The `loginHandler()` should be redirecting the user to a Google login with the random `state` value. Once the user logs into google and approves of your application having access to your data, the user will be redirected in the browser back to your application, which appears to be handled by the `/auth` path and `authHandler()` function.

The `authHandler()` should just be verifying the status from the login via Google and updating the user's session to be indicate that the user is authorized. It usually then redirects the user to another page that that is worthwhile to the logged in user, such as `/calenders` or some other page that makes sense for the application and user. So in reality, the ugly `/auth?state=blah&code=blah` is very short lived, like a fraction of a second.